# why execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") with python selenium returns 0

Tags: python, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWiwN.jpg).
Below is my python code.
`get()` is working well.
But after performing `execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")`, `lastHeight` returns `0`.
And movement on chromedriver webpage is none.
And then `newHeight` also returns `0`.
Why do they return `0`?

```
def getVideoData(self):
     self.chromeBrowser.get(self.videoTab)
     lastHeight = self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
     print(lastHeight)
     while True:
        self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        self.chromeBrowser.implicitly_wait(0.5)
        newHeight = self.chromeBrowser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print(newHeight)
        if newHeight == lastHeight:
           break
        lastHeight = newHeight
```

image shows correct result of get(). To show a image, click "enter image description here"

Comment: can you add the screen capture of the page?

Comment: [@Swadhikar C] I uploaded result of get().
image link is "enter image description here".
Click it.

Comment: Can you try with `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` and see whether it works?

Comment: [@KDM] Thank you KDM. 
I modified all execute_script() from `document.body.scrollHeight` to `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`.
So I got a return value `2194`.
And then `execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")` is excuted, but `newHeight` returns `2194`
definitely, I saw updated videos on chromdriver and scrollbar was extended.
Although elements to scroll down remained, `newHeight` returns `2194`.
Why `newHeight` returns `2194`?
I changed `implicitly_wait()` until 10 seconds, but no effects.

Comment: And only 30 initial elements about video data are searched when find elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume you are trying to scroll to the end of the page using selenium. While analyzing the issue, I found that there is a bug with javascript `document.body.scrollHeight` which is malfunctioning for pages like YouTube.com which has floating web elements. Refer to [Bug details](https://github.com/google/caja/issues/1124). I have given a try with `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` and it looks to work good for this page.

```
>>> driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
3120
```

Having said that the below directives proves to scroll to the end of the page.

```
>>> height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
>>> driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(height) + ");")
```

[image: Scrolled to bottom of page using script]

If you wish to remove `Chrome is being controlled by automated software` info bar please use the below commands to launch browser.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('disable_infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thank you Swadhikar C.  I modified from `document.body.scrollHeight` to `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`. And then i got a scrollHeight value. 
But loop is performed only once. Although page to scroll down remains, `newHeight` and `lastHeight` same. Results form each page in youtube channel are different. For example, one page is performed above logic, but another page isn't performed above logic.
I don't understand this situation.

Comment: Great answer! I was using the document.body.scrollHeight code as it was being used in multiple blogs but it was not working in youtube.com on which I wanted to scrape the data. Thanks for adding your answer!