# problem adding condition to scrape w/ infinite scroll - Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a website w/ infinite scroll and as my infinite scroll works fine using selenium, when I add conditions, It just logs data till the first scroll
What could be the possible problem?

(same scrolls perfectly w/o conditions)

My code:

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(randint(1,10))
    for a in page.find_all('a', href=True): <--Condition
        print("Found the URL:", a['href'])  <----Condition


    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Comment: It could be that `document.body.scrollHeight` returns `0` even after a scroll. Please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702698/10409093 and try with `driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")`.

Comment: @WholeBrain Scrolling here isn't an issue. but recording the data is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def scroll(driver, timeout):
    scroll_pause_time = timeout

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            # If heights are the same it will exit the function
            break
        last_height = new_height

scroll(driver, randint(2,5))
page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
count = 0
for a in page.find_all('a', href=True):
    count+=1
    print(count)
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```