# why window.scrollTo() doesn't work with pages like YouTube?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape with Selenium but I need to load all the content of the page by moving to the end of the website. But when I execute: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
the program doesn't do anything at all. I wonder if it's because the page that I'm scraping has a personalized scrollbar.

[image]

Comment: Include your code in the question, not as a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why execute\_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") with python selenium returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690101/why-execute-scriptreturn-document-body-scrollheight-with-python-selenium-ret)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `document.body.scrollHeight` is zero, so it doesn't scroll anything.

You can scroll to an arbitrary large value to scroll down or instead use `document.documentElement.scrollHeight`.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690101/why-execute-scriptreturn-document-body-scrollheight-with-python-selenium-ret/51702698) for more details.